# multiple inputs of the same name in an html form

Tags: python, html

I have some html code that contains a form. When submitted it sends a post request to a server. The form has various inputs, each with a name and a value, however there are some inputs with the same name.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <input name="name" value="val">
    <input name="name" value="val">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

First, I am confused as to how there can be two values of the same name. Please note that I have tried removing one of the instances of `<input name="name" value="val">` however this returns an error so it seems that both instances are needed.

Second, I am trying to convert this to a python request using the request library.

I have the following request:

```
requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS).json()
```

Where PARAMS is a dictionary of the various inputs. For example:

```
PARAMS = {'name':"val"}
```

However, being a dictionary, I can't have multiple instances of the same value. How do I make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are duplicated names then the values will be in an array with the name. The demo below sends to a live test server and the response is directed to an `<iframe>`

```html
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target="response">
  <input name="name" value="val">
  <input name="name" value="val">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<iframe name='response'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is to use input arrays. With them, you can have many inputs sharing the same name, and in the server side, the data will be treated as an array. So the HTML would be:

```html
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <input name="name[]" value="val1">
    <input name="name[]" value="val2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```